# Change color of Reorder icon in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I change color of Reorder icon (three horizontal lines)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom image you like by giving this code within your `UITableViewCell` class.

```swift
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if editing {
        for view in subviews where view.description.contains("Reorder") {
            for case let subview as UIImageView in view.subviews {
                subview.image = UIImage(named: "yourimage.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                subview.tintColor = .red // your desired color here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code! Is there any way to change only the color?

Comment: You can't change the colour of the existing 3-lines view. Check the work-around I've posted. I've added the method to change the colour too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    static let controlClassName = "UITableViewCellReorderControl"

    /// This shouldn't need to be done, but setting the cell tint color doesn't affect the reorder image icon
    /// when editing a table view.
    /// - Parameter color: (UIColor) The color to change the gripper image icon to.
    func setReorderImageColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        for view in subviews where view.classForCoder.description() == Self.controlClassName {
            if let imageView = view.subviews
                .first(where: { $0.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) }) as? UIImageView {
                imageView.image = imageView.image?.withTintColor(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then within your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    if isEditing { setReorderImageColor(.systemOrange) }
}
```